# Поддержка математических функций на аппаратном уровне GPU

Tags: функции, gpu

Поддерживаются ли математические функции на аппаратном уровне GPU 
  или при их вызове в программе(если использовать шейдер) они обрабатываются CPU? 
  Как можно узнать какие функции поддерживаются данным конкретным GPU?

Comment: железка ничего не делает при помощи центрального процессора, сама считает, иначе какой в этом смысл? она и сделана для того, чтобы много считать

Comment: математика на видео карте ориентирована на тригонометрию, я не математик, по-этому не могу сказать каких функций там нет, лучше скажите какие функции Вас интересуют..

Comment: Основные тригонометрические  и векторные функции. У меня в программе есть много расчетов, связанных с математикой. Поэтому появилась такая идея как реализовать это в виде compute shader при наличии соответствующей видеокарты.

Comment: Вы же хотите получить ответ, почему бы не задать вопрос конкретнее. Вы пишите основные функции, а какие по Вашему функции основные? На каком языке программирования написана Ваша программа?

Comment: под основными я понимаю sin,cos,tan,atan2,скалярное произведение,умножение матрицы на вектор,транспонирование. Буду благодарен если присоветуют книгу по этой тематике.

Comment: все это есть, как и длина вектора, вектороное произведение и многое другое. Толковых книг по шейдерам я не встречал, сам изучал интернет, в попытках это познать.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. А можете ссылки накидать на сайты?

Comment: транспонирование - существует не с первой версии glsl, не помню точно с какой, не пользовался им.

Comment: Это не так страшно. В принципе можно и заранее транспонировать матрицу. Шейдеры сильно выигрывают в скорости скажем в сравнении с glDrawArrays, glDrawPixels?

Comment: https://webglfundamentals.org - у меня на телефоне сейчас не открылся, однако очень неплохо и не сложно и с переводом написано, хотя и для веб и про графику, а еще спека на https://www.khronos.org

Comment: Это сайт у меня в хроме тоже не открылся. khronos.org я поглядываю часто но там примеров нет.

Comment: есть cuda, для обычных вычислений, не связаных с графикой, но до нее у меня еще руки не доходили - сам я в основном балуюсь шейдерами для графики в веб

Comment: про cuda я знаю но пока далеко еще до него. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: примеров нет, но есть описания и сигнатуры функций, что помогает, примеры - я нахожу их в сети. есть codepen, shadertoy, vertexshaderart и еще другие песочницы, в которых этого добра хватает :), на этом ресурсе я иногда пытаюсь изображать крутизну с метой webgl / glsl https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl?tab=Active

Comment: вот сайт одного гуру Inigo Quilez, я многое понял именно тут - https://www.iquilezles.org

Comment: Спасибо. Будем посмотреть!